# Transforming geometry points coordinates to WGS84 in geodataframe

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, python-3, pyproj

I have shapefile that has been brought into my script as a geodataframe. Initially, it shows no `crs` although the source originally had a datum = `NAD83`. 
[image: Notebook]

I want the coordinates for the geometry (the POINT; not the fields LATITUDE and LONGITUDE) to be in `WGS84` and I assume I need to do more than simply set the geodataframe to `WGS84` like this : `bldg_feat_cent_df.crs = {'init' :'4326'}`. It seems the point coordinates need to be `transformed` to `WGS84`. I have tried a number of different things using `pyproj`, `shapely` and `functools` but I am not sure how to correctly apply them:

```
import pyproj
from pyproj import Proj, transform
from functools import partial
from shapely.ops import transform
....
state_feat = state_bldg_centroid
bldg_cents_cols = ['uniqueid', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'GEOID', 'CensusPop', 'HU_Pop']
bldg_feat_cent_df = 
gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(records(bldg_cent_cb_intersects_gdb, bldg_cents_cols))
...
//Get a Geoseries of the geometry
geometry=bldg_feat_cent_df.geometry
project = partial(
  pyproj.transform,
  pyproj.Proj(bldg_feat_cent_df.crs), # source coordinate system
  pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'))
```

This throws an error `RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'` and I am not sure what to do from there. Any suggestions on how to accomplish my goal of transforming my points to `WGS84`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is a pyproj 1x [issue](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/134).

I would recommend [installing pyproj 2+](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html). You can do this with [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html) using the conda-forge channel:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n geo geopandas
conda activate geo
```

Or, you can install the latest version with python wheels:

```
pip install --ignore-installed pyproj==2.4.0
```

EDIT:
Side note, you can use the [to_crs()](http://geopandas.org/projections.html) method on the geodataframe to re-project once you have the updated version of pyproj.